# php mysql Query result with %Like%

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I am stuck with the query result and need help plz.

My sample column
`How are you`
`what is your name`
`where are you from`
`whats the age of the youth`

Now this is my column in Table and I query the below

```
  $search='you';
  $s=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from tblxyz where column1 is LIKE '%{$key}%'");
```

I am getting the result of all the 4 rows as there is "you" in all, But I would like to get the result of the exact word which SQL searched, so the result from the 4th row would be "youth". How to get those words which SQL found based on my query.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you need that so just apply like after the string you search: '{$key}%' In this way you search for the string that exactly begins with YOU and all other char after.

Comment: No That is not what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Remove is and remove braces

Answer (score 2):

try this query.

```
  $search='you';
     $sql=" SELECT * FROM tblxyz WHERE column1 like '%".$search."%'";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, But this also gives me the whole column as result, But I just need the word as result from which it has matched. Thanks

Comment: instead of  WHERE column1 like '%".$search."%' use WHERE column 1=$search

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

to get the exact word don't use `%`

```
$search='you';
$s=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from tblxyz where column1 is LIKE '{$search}'");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but my question is little different. With the query above I get the result as the entire column (All 4 of them), But the result I need is 1. you, 2. you, 3. you and 4. youth, This is what I am looking for, Thanks in advance

Comment: so you want result from the column which contains word `you` in the string. It doesn't matter if it has any letter preceding and succeeding it. So if word youth is there it should show that in result.

Comment: Ok so now the result is showing from all the 4 rows, The result i get is 1) how are you, 2) what is your name, 3) where are you from and 4) whats the age of the youth. I am getting all the 4 which is fine, But I want the result to be 1) you, 2) your, 3) you, 4) youth. Only these words. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are looking for the word `you` and you want to select only data with the word `you.` In this case, you might want to use `REGEXP`.

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE tname RLIKE "[[:<:]]you[[:>:]]"
```

The above can be used for exact word matching.